# React mui-datatable pagination starts at 0, instead of 1

Tags: reactjs, datatable

So, I have a MUI-Datatable, which I'm trying to paginate server side, these are the datatable options,

```js
    const [netflixData, setNetflixData] = useState({});
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const countPerPage = 10;
    const getNetflixData = () => {
    axios.get(`/netflix/ranks/?page=${page}`, config).then(res => {
      setNetflixData(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      setNetflixData({});
    });
    };
    const options = {
        filter: true,
        filterType: 'multiselect',
        serverSide: true,
        count: netflixData.count,
        rowsPerPage: countPerPage,
        rowsPerPageOptions: [],
        onTableChange: (action, tableState) => {
        if (action === 'changePage') {
            setPage(tableState.page);
        } else {
            console.log('action not handled.');
        }
      },
    };
    useEffect(() =>{
        getNetflixData()
    }, [page]
    );
      <MUIDataTable
        title={"Netflix Rankings"}
        data={netflixData.results}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
```

Basically, on page load `tableState.page` should be `1`, but, nothing happens, so when I click 'next page', it changes to `1`, 3rd page, `tableState.page` is `2`, so if I go back twice, it'll be `0`, which doesn't exist.

I tried adding the option, `page: 1`, but that just defaults me to the second page of the table. Any ideas on how to set `tableState.page = 1` on page/table load?

Answer (score 2):

Try using setPage(tableState.page + 1). Your page number on the state will be one-based and on the datatable it will be zero-based. I don't know if you can make the datatable paging one-based.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting your state with "page + 1". Here's a sample code to help you use MUI Data Table easier:

If you are using [MUI Data table](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#data-table), The DataGrid Component inside of it has parameters to use for server-side handling. In your case to handle pagination on the server side you can use "[onPaginationModelChange](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#DataGrid-prop-onPaginationModelChange)" and use the "model" object which is one of this function's outputs. You should also set the "[paginationMode](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#DataGrid-prop-paginationMode)" to "server" so it will prevent the default pagination behavior of the MUI Data table:

```
onPaginationModelChange={paginationHandler}
paginationMode = "server"
```

Then you can use a "UseEffect" to update your rows like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`/netflix/ranks/?page=${page}`).then(res => {
    setNetflixData(res.data);
  }).catch(err => {
    setNetflixData({});
  })}, [page])
```

after all a sample code for the MUI Data table to use it server-side will be like this (Remember to pass the columns parameter to DataGrid):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export default function MUIDataTable() {
  const [netflixData, setNetflixData] = useState({});
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const countPerPage = 10;

  const paginationHandler = (model) => {
    setPage(model.page + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`/netflix/ranks/?page=${page}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setNetflixData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setNetflixData({});
      });
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100%",
        width: "95%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={netflixData}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: countPerPage },
          },
        }}
        onPaginationModelChange={paginationHandler}
        paginationMode="server" // When you are handling pagination using back-end you should set this property to "server"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```